# Notation for estimator in statistics

Tags: statistics, notation

I'm trying to understand the estimator notation $\hat\theta$ and what is correct use.

If $\hat\theta = \hat\mu$, is $\hat\mu(X) = \overline X$?

Is $\hat p(X,n) = \dfrac{X}{n}$?

If not, what is correct notation for these?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to start by naming the distribution.
If $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are iid $N(\mu, \sigma_0^2),$ with
$\sigma_0$ known and $\mu$ to be estimated, then one
might consider several estimators of $\mu.$ If $\bar X$ is
one of them, one might write $\hat \mu = \bar X.$ If the
median is another, then that might be denoted by $\tilde \mu.$
Some authors like to reserve the 'hat' notation $\hat{}$ for
maximum likelihood estimators, or ones with some other optimal
properties.

If a large number of different estimators for
the same population parameter is under consideration, they
might just be called something like $T_1,$ $T_2,$ and so on, without
resorting to 'decorations' on the letter denoting the parameter.

Attempting more compact notation, some authors invent
their own shorthand, which should be clearly explained at
its first usage. I have seen a vast variety of different
notations by different authors--some clearly explained and
some not. Perhaps a failure of clear explanation has
given rise to your question.